# How to get value from table appended in javascript

Tags: javascript, android

My code:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  $("#myfav").append("<tr><td>" + "<a href='#' class='ui-btn' style='background-color:white;color:#03d3aa;' onClick='window.onclick= prepareButton()'>" + arr[i].username + "<br>" + arr[i].phoneno + "<br>" + "Status: " + arr[i].status + "</a></td></tr>");
}

function prepareButton() {

  $(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
      autoOpen: true,
      show: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 1000
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "explode",
        duration: 1000
      }
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog" style="display:none;background-color:white;">
  <a href="#" onclick="add()" class="ui-btn">Add as Loved Ones</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="view()" class="ui-btn">View Profile</a>
</div>
```

Right now i have a list of contacts, when on click would run the function `prepareButton()` which would show a dialog with buttons.

I need to get the value of `arr[i].username` and `arr[i].phoneno` of the contact clicked in order to pass this value to the `add()` button and save it in my database through AJAX.

However, I could not seem to get these two values as it is appended in a table format using Javascript.

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of `window.onclick`, add `$('.commonClass').on("click", function(){ var data = $(this).text().split(/[\r\n]/)})`. Also if you can share sample `arr`, it would be easier to debug and help

Comment: Basically arr is the output from my database values which I call using php

Comment: var arr = JSON.parse(response);

Answer (score 0):

You can add the parameters to the prepareButton function and when you append rows to the table just make sure that you call the function with the provided parameters. Just like the way you show them:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  $("#myfav").append("<tr><td>" + "<a href='#' class='ui-btn' style='background-color:white;color:#03d3aa;' onClick='window.onclick= prepareButton(\'"+arr[i].username+"\', \'"+ arr[i].phoneno+"\')'>" + arr[i].username + "<br>" + arr[i].phoneno + "<br>" + "Status: " + arr[i].status + "</a></td></tr>");
}

function prepareButton(username, phoneno) {

  $(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
      autoOpen: true,
      show: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 1000
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "explode",
        duration: 1000
      }
    });
  });
}
```

I didn't ran the code.

Comment: Instead of adding `I didn't ran the code.`, run the code and add verifiable sample

Answer (score 0):

As commented, all you have to do is fetch text and split values but since string parsing is not good, you should try replacing `<br>`s with `<p>` as the are by default block elements.

Also you should avoid assigning `onclick=someFunc()`. You are already using jQuery. Use `$(selector).on('click', ...)`

#### Sample Code

```js
function getRowHTML(user) {
  return "" +
    "<tr>" +
      "<td>" +
        "<a href='#' class='ui-btn userDetails'>" +
          "<p>" + user.username + "</p>" +
          "<p>" + user.phoneno + "</p>" +
          "<p>" + "Status: " + user.status + "</p>" +
        "</a>" +
      "</td>" +
    "</tr>"
}

function createHTML(arr) {
  var htmlStr = arr.reduce(function(p, c) {
    p += getRowHTML(c);
    return p;
  }, "");
  $("#myfav").append(htmlStr);

  //for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  //  $("#myfav").append(getRowHTML(arr[i]));
  //}
}

function registerEvents() {
  $(document).on("click", ".userDetails", function() {
    var paras = $(this).find('p');
    var data = $.map(paras, function(el) {
      return $(el).text()
    });
    console.log(data)
    return false;
  })
}

function prepareButton() {
  $("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    show: {
      effect: "blind",
      duration: 1000
    },
    hide: {
      effect: "explode",
      duration: 1000
    }
  });
}

$(function() {
  var data = [{
    username: "foo",
    phoneno: "12345678",
    status: "test"
  }, {
    username: "foo1",
    phoneno: "12345",
    status: "test1"
  }, {
    username: "foo2",
    phoneno: "123458",
    status: "test2"
  }, {
    username: "foo3",
    phoneno: "123678",
    status: "test3"
  }]

  createHTML(data)
  registerEvents();
})
```

```css
.userDetails {
  background-color: white;
  color: #03d3aa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myfav"></table>
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog" style="display:none;background-color:white;">
  <a href="#" onclick="add()" class="ui-btn">Add as Loved Ones</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="view()" class="ui-btn">View Profile</a>
</div>
```

**Note:** I have not changed part of `onclick="add()"` or `="view()"`.